# How do control  the boundary regularity of the Legendre transformation domain from a convex function

Tags: convexity, convex-geometry

Let f(x) be a strongly convex smooth function (its Hessian matrix is positive definite) defined in a convex domain D, introduce the Legendre transformation
$$x=(x_1,...,x_n)\rightarrow (\xi_1,...,\xi_n),\xi_i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i},$$
$$u(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)=x_i\xi_i-f$$
The Legendre transformation domain W is defined by:
$$W=((\xi_1,...,\xi_n)|\xi_i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}, x\in D )$$
I want to know the regularity of the boundary of W, (can assume the domain W is bounded)
what conditions to make the boundary $\partial W$ smooth or $C^2$?

Comment: If $f$ is strongly convex and defined in a nbd of $\bar D$, it's gradient $\nabla f$ is a (monotone) diffeomorphism, so $\partial W$ is $C^2$ if $\partial D$ is $C^2$ and $f$ is $C^3$ on a nbd of $\bar D$.

Comment: In my question, f(x) may be defined on
the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ (this situation is my interest), for example, the following function (known as hyperbolic affine hypersphere):
$$f(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{x_1\cdots x_n}, x_i>0, 1\leq i\leq n.$$
Choose suitable coordinates, this graph can be 
represented by another function $\tilde{f}$ defined on
the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the Legendre transformation domain of $\tilde{f}$ is a simplex.
